# is it possible to use a vector object a dependent variable in GLM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, ecology

I would like to write certain model in R.

I would like to o use a vector object as a dependent variable in my general linear model. The model is supposed to explain how some environmental factors, and their interactions, explain the shape of a species community composition.

The vector object is supposed to look something like [0,2,0,3,1] and designate species community composition. Each dimension of the vector is intended to be a different species, and their values are intended to show the abundance of species.

Does anybody know in which package is it possible to do it/ is it possible at all?

If anybody has a better idea how to model such a relation, I am also open to ideas ;)

Thanks in advance,

Best wishes,

Jacek

Answer (score 1):

There's more to say about the current answer from @Circus pygargus than fits into a comment.

First, the answer might be correct about `glm()` models not allowing vectors as outcomes, except that for binomial or quasi-binomial the response can be a "two-column matrix with the columns giving the numbers of successes and failures" so that each outcome could be considered a 2-dimensional vector.

For standard `lm()` models, however, a numeric response matrix is possible and forms the basis of multivariate linear models.

Second, the answer tends to downplay the value of modeling individual species abundance when it says:

> And you won't link community composition to environmental factors, you will only link the abundance of one species (or one community metric) to these factors.

You can include all the data in a single model by including `species` as a predictor in the model. Differences among species with respect to environmental factors could be included as interaction terms in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to use a vector as dependent variable for a linear model.

First option, if you really want to link abiotic variables to community with a model, is to calculate community metrics (e.g. Shannon Index, Species Richness, biological traits, etc.) and use each metric as dependent variable in models with your environmental factors as explanatory variables. An alternative can be using variables linked to a unique species (e.g. abundance) as dependent variable but I am pretty sure you can't use a vector of abundance in a linear model. And you won't link community composition to environmental factors, you will only link the abundance of one species (or one community metric) to these factors.

Second option, what I would recommand here, is to use multivariate methods. Canonical Correspondence Analysis might be relevent in your case but you should read some papers (e.g. [this excellent article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4769650/)) and check this [great website about multivariate methods in ecology](https://sites.google.com/site/mb3gustame/) before you pick a procedure.